# Use sectionedrecyclerviewadapter But compiler Error

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, sections, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I have to use recycler section in my project, but when I add the tool below:

[SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter)

when I add gradle

```
implementation 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.2.0'
```

then, the NotificationCompact

```
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
```

Can't be found!
How should I do to use recycler section?

Comment: I don't see what NotificationCompat has to with a RecyclerView.

Comment: It's another class in the project.